# How late can direct deposit be?

Tags: management, salary

My girlfriend and I normally receive our direct deposits at the same time on Tuesdays around 11pm. She received hers last night and I’m still waiting on mine. Any help or information on this matter  would be appreciated.

Comment: Location is everything. Regulations could vary by country.

Comment: Do you both work for the same company?

Comment: Are you asking what the maximum amount of time is for a financial institution to process a direct deposit is, or are you asking how late an employer is allowed to be in paying you? The answer to the former should be available at the bank/credit union web site. The latter depends on where you live. (If you're in the United States, include your state.)

Answer (score 5):

Typically direct deposits are **consistent**, and in my experience never late.

As an example, I get paid every other Friday.  So on Friday morning, I sign in and check to see that the deposit hit my account, so I know to continue working for the company.

Holidays do factor in.  For instance this year Christmas falls on a Friday, so I will get paid Thursday the 24th to account for the bank holiday.

**And to answer your question**:  if you both work at the same company I would be concerned and discuss with your manager asap.  If not, I would verify with your company that there isn't some sort of holiday at play, and if there isn't discuss with your manager asap.

**Short answer**:  Contact your manager.

Answer (score 1):

There can be all sorts of reasons why a direct deposit is late:

- You made a mistake, your time card was wrong.
- The payroll processing system had an issue.
- The bank had a problem.
- Holidays.

I have experience all of these over the years.

These are all fixable, you just have to know who to contact.

Some issues are more troubling. that would be if there was a financial problem either at the employer, or at the payroll company.

Start looking at what is in common. That means you might have to talk to the bank, or your co-workers. I would start with HR. If multiple people are having an issue that will let them know where to start looking. If you co-workers are also having the same problem, tell them to contact HR. Your company internet might provide you with a POC for payroll issues.